# what does "non-filtering clauses" mean when running linq on parse.com?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com and the .NET SDK.

I am trying to create a "feed" containing posts from users that Current user is following as well as posts from current user (posts that user himself has created).

To do this, I have created 3 queries:

```
            var activities = from activity in ParseObject.GetQuery("Activity").Skip(skip).Limit(limit)
                             where activity.Get<string>("type") == "follow"
                             && activity["fromUser"] == ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<ParseUser>(id)
                             select activity;

            var stories = from story in ParseObject.GetQuery("Story").Include("createdBy")
                          orderby story.CreatedAt descending
                            join activity in activities on story["createdBy"] equals activity["toUser"]
                            select story;

            var userstories = from story in ParseObject.GetQuery("Story").Include("createdBy")
                              where story["createdBy"] == ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<ParseUser>(id)
                              select story;

            var query = stories.Or(userstories);

            var results = await query.FindAsync();
```

But this doesnt work and I get this error:

"ExceptionMessage": "None of the queries in an or query can have non-filtering clauses"

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out if anyone cares.

Apparently, you can not use "Include" or "Orderby" on any of the subqueries.

This is the final result that worked:

```
var activities = from activity in ParseObject.GetQuery("Activity")
                             where activity.Get<string>("type") == "follow"
                             && activity["fromUser"] == ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<ParseUser>(id)
                             select activity;

            var stories = from story in ParseObject.GetQuery("Story")
                           join activity in activities on story["createdBy"] equals activity["toUser"]
                           select story;

            var userstories = from story in ParseObject.GetQuery("Story")
                              where story["createdBy"] == ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<ParseUser>(id)
                              select story;

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = stories.Or(userstories).Skip(skip).Limit(limit).Include("createdBy")
                .OrderBy("-createdAt");

            var results = await query.FindAsync();
```